# jquery hover bubble causing a looping blinking effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-hover

I have a problem with bubbling  (i think)

I have an input

On hover I append a div with a click event to the parent of the input, the second hover function is to remove the said appended div.

The problem is, as the overlay is on top of the div i am appending to, when the mouse is over the overlay the mouse out function is called which then triggers the mouse over.. etc etc..

http://jsfiddle.net/N7FFB/

```
var clear = $('<div class="keyword-clear-icon">').css({
                left            : $('#searchtext').width() - 20,
            }).attr('title','Clear');

$("#dashboard-searchbox #searchtext").hover(
    function(){
        $(clear).click(function(){
            $("input#searchtext").val('');
        });
        $('#dashboard-searchbox').append(clear);
    },
    function(){
       $('#dashboard-searchbox').find('.keyword-clear-icon').remove();
    }
);
```

Is there a std way of achieving this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply the hover to the `#dashboard-searchbox` container instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/N7FFB/2/

#### Javascript

```
$("#dashboard-searchbox").hover(
    function(){
        $(clear).click(function(){
            $("input#searchtext").val('');
        });
        $('#dashboard-searchbox').append(clear);
    },
    function(){
       $('#dashboard-searchbox').find('.keyword-clear-icon').remove();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using javascript you *can* use a `search` type input box:

```
<input id="searchtext" name="SearchText" 
       type="search" placeholder="Anywhere or anything…" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/N7FFB/1/

Comment: what version of html support this attribute?

Comment: @John you can use an HTML5 shiv/shim to make it work in all browsers.

Comment: And now you do @John :-D